# Google ads API is down

Tags: google-ads-api, google-docs-api

Does google ads API work?

When I click the [google ads API document](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/start), I get "Service Unavailable".

1. Where can I see this API status, and when it's back?
2. Can I use this API to create custom audience/lookalike audience just like facebook ads API?
3. (Additional) I am NodeJS developer, is there any library that is already working well with ads API?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can view the Google Ads API status here: https://ads.google.com/status#hl=en&v=status
2. Yes you can create custom audiences in Google Ads API, see documentation here: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/remarketing/audience-types/custom-audiences
3. Yes, I have had experience using this attached one: https://github.com/Opteo/google-ads-api  . I used it for GAQL queries and a few bid change things and it worked good. It is not as documented as Python's Client Library.

Lemme know if you have any other questions, hope this helps.

Comment: It was down but up again week ago. Thank you!